# Two tails or one tail McNemar's test in a binary classification problem. Which one should i choose?

Tags: classification, binary-data, contingency-tables, mcnemar-test, one-tailed-test

I'm using `McNemar's test` for compare two designed models in a binary classification problem. As you know we have two kinds of this test. `One tail` and `two tails`.

What is difference of these kinds and which one should i choose for calculating my `p-value`? I'm using `Yates's correction for continuity` for this test.

Comment: I suggest considering the Wilcoxon signed ranks test instead of McNemars. See [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf).

Comment: @Marc, in a dichotomous case Wilcoxon test = Sign test =McNemar's test.

Comment: Oh that's embarassing. Thanks for that clarification @ttnphns.